# AppleTV ethernet over HDMI?

Tags: appletv, hdmi, ethernet

I have an AppleTV 4K connected to a Sony screen over HDMI. The AppleTV is connected to the Internet via WiFi, the Sony is deliberately *not* connected - just power and HDMI. Recently I have learned that there is such a thing as [ethernet over HDMI](https://www.hdmi.org/manufacturer/hdmi_1_4/hec.aspx). How can I confirm that the AppleTV is not providing this to the Sony? I don't want the latter to phone home, "upgrade" its firmware, run Android apps or anything else - I just intend for it to be a dumb (i.e. non-smart) screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HDMI Ethernet Channel never took off, and no commercially available devices support it. Your Apple TV, HDMI cable and TV would all have to support it, and it’s almost certain that none of them do.

See AVforums' [List of HEC and ARC enabled devices?](https://www.avforums.com/threads/list-of-hec-and-arc-enabled-devices.2033897/) discussion.

Comment: The company I work for has been looking for chips that support Ethernet over HDMI (would have been a nice feature for a new product): There just aren't any on the market. That was the state in December 2017. The ARM SoC (A10X) used in the AppleTV 4K is proprietary to Apple, but it is based on a standard A10, which doesn't have this feature and it is well-known what Apple changed in their version. Adding ethernet to the HDMI wasn't on that list .